# Работа с формой Angular

Tags: angular

есть таблица в которую входит Имя клиента и номер контракта ,нужно через форму добавлять в таблицу эти данные.

[image: Таблица]

[image: Html код]

[image: Angular]

Comment: Что-то не видно кода.

Comment: ну я думал через $scope.addNew = function() {  
                                $scope.customerArr.push($scope.customerInput)
}но как в массив добавлять сразу с 2 input-ов данные

Comment: можно так: `$scope.customerArr.push({name:$scope.customerInput, contract: $scope.contactInput})`